# Extract text from span element using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to extract the contact number (XXXXX-XXXXXX) from the following HTML code using Selenium webdriver's *find_element_by_xpath* method.

```
 <div id="contact-info">
                    <div class="a">
                        <div class="b">
                            <table class="c">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="d">
                                        <div class="e">Contact Info</span></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="f">
                                        <div></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="g">
                            <div class="h">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="i"><span class="j">Mobile</span></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="k">
                                            <div class="random_class_name"><span><span dir="ltr">XXXXX-XXXXXX</span></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

This is my code for extracting the required data-

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="contact-info"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/span[1]').text)
```

But I'm thrown with an exception saying the element can't be located. What am I possibly doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `Mobile-Number` you can take the reference of the text `Mobile` and find the next sibling.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and following xpath.

```
print(WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[.//div[contains(.,'Mobile')]]/following-sibling::td[1]/div"))).text)
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I'm getting a TimeoutException this time

Comment: @AbdullahShahriar : The `xpath` is fine.I have tested before posted as an answer.Could you just check if there any `iframe` above your table element?

Comment: Sorry, I was scraping the wrong file. The solution you posted works fine! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Correct your XPath with :

```
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@dir="ltr"]').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
contactNumber = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='random_class_name']//span[1]//span")))
print contactNumber.text
```

or

```
contactNumber = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'XXXXX-XXXXXX')]")))
print contactNumber.text
```

**Note** : add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Upddated Section:** 
Check your table is in the iframe if so then use below code to swiutch to iframe ;

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Comment: check if your table in the iframe if so you need to switch to iframe before using above code: Please refer updated section to switch to iframe

Comment: There's no iframe above the table element. But thanks for pointing it out. I was scraping the wrong file and so the error was raised. Your solution works completely fine!

Comment: I have another question in mind, what if the class name random_class_name was not known, how can I access the element?

Comment: you mean same contact number element ? if so then you can directly use //span[contains(text(), 'XXXXX-XXXXXX')]

Comment: No, assume 'XXXXX-XXXXXX' is also unknown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211243/discussion-between-dipak-bachhav-and-abdullah-shahriar).